# call more time jquery plugins (rollerblade)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I want to call rollerblade.js plugin each time a picture is clicked, but it works just once, & didn't work when I changed my HTML code...
I tried to call it in a function and set `onclick` to my picture, but that didn't work.

```
$("#show").rollerblade({
    imageArray: arrayOfImages,
    sensitivity: 5,
    drag: true,
    auto: false,
    edgeStop: false
});
```

Comment: Please, read [how to ask useful questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: typos, grammar, clarification